# how to place a rounded button at corner of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place a rounded button over the edge of two edit boxes which are in vertical mode as in the following figure:

[image]

How can I implement this design?

Comment: design a image and set the image as background to the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the two `EditText` components in a `RelativeLayout`, one below other and after that in the same relative Layout you can simply set the circle button the property `align_parent_right` and `center_vertical`, you can then set a smaller width.

The `Button` will appear just above your EditTexts in this way.. so if you also want that gray border, you will have to add that to the button's background but it shouldn't be that hard.

I hope it helps you.